# Feedback that an agreed tool is non-intuitive

Tags: culture, collaboration

In a meeting two teams, mine and another one, quite lightheartedly agreed to my proposal to use a common and very popular tool for a project. It is actually a market leading browser-based collaboration tool allowing integrated texting and graphing, which would be though new to them.

My team delivered initial documentation and shared access using the tool agreed upon.

After that, other team's contribution comes as an attachment per email in a proprietary format and a PDF export, where they needed to rework our initial input to get started, with a comment that the tool we had agreed upon was a "counter-intuitive to understand it in a couple of minutes".

How to react?

**UPDATE**

Both tools are recommended and available for use in the organization; my proposal suggested to use that one as it allows for faster collaboration and zero effort in sharing.

Comment: What made them agree to use a tool that they then refuse - did they not listen? Or is the other tool **so** much better? Or are they just more experienced with it?

Comment: All of those tools are incredibly silly, stupid, and annoying.  (We will look back on those "tools!" like looking back on flare pants or any other stupid craze.) One thing to beware of is that you are suffering "fanboy" about one particular one of those online tools.  They are all : stupid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Schedule a meeting and give them a tutorial.

Comment: well is worth to try, if they accept that.

Comment: Be aware though that the only thing more annoying than tools - - - is demos of tools.  If I told someone a tool annoyed me, and they offered a demo, I'd assume they were just being a smarty-pants.  Myself and most people know how to use tools, but if they're annoying they're annoying.  In some (not all) cases an offer of a demo might just bring more tool annoyance  :O

Comment: @Fattie I might agree if they hadn't (reportedly) said "counter-intuitive to understand it in a couple of minutes".  A lot of tools aren't able to be grasped in that amount of time, yet they are nonetheless useful tools.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by understanding what it is that makes the tool of choice counter-intuitive. Only then would I start to look at what other tools are available and check to see if they are more intuitive. Lastly I'd look at cons associated with the alternative tools and then agree on one after some functional testing of all of them.

Comment: takes too much time given both tools are available and in use in the organization

Comment: Don't read anything in to the "counter-intuitive" comment by the other party.  It's very likely they just "hate the tool".  When folks give a "reason" why they hate something, it's usually just a rationale.